# Wordpress search results all have same link

Tags: wordpress, search

When users search on my site, the results are all different but the results all have the same URL. Search.php has this code:

```
   <div class="container-archive-article-body">
                                <div class="container-archive-article-historical-date">
                                    <h2 class="archive-article-historical-date">
<?php
            $date = get_post_meta ( $post->ID, 'pure_tih_app_times_date', true );
            
            $gdih_ymd = '';
            if ( ! empty ( $date ) )
            {
                $gdih_ymd = DateTime::createFromFormat ( 'Y-m-d', $date );

                if ( ! empty ( $gdih_ymd ) )
                {
                    echo date_format ( $gdih_ymd, 'F j, Y' );
                }
            }
?>
                                    </h2>
                                </div>

                                <div class="container-archive-article-title">
                                    <h3 class="archive-article-title">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $the_permalink; ?>" title="<?php echo $the_title; ?>">
                                            <?php echo $the_title; ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </h3>
                                </div>
                                <div class="archive-article-excerpt">
                                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Any ideas on why the URL for all results is the same? Thank you for any help!

Comment: What is the value of $the_permalink ? use the_permalink() or the_title() for getting current post permalink and title

Answer (score 0):

Using the native Wordpress method [get_the_permalink()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_permalink/) fixes your link URL problem.

Change the link element code accordingly to:

```
<a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink; ?>" <!-- other attributes -->>
    //link text
</a>
```